# How to calculate the element to be divided equally

Tags: javascript

in my company, big data is saved as an excel file and I have converted the data to a JSON file for processing, but it's difficult for a novice like me like this

```js
var Task = [{
id1: 01,
id2: 02,
money: 400
},{
id1: 03,
id2: 02,
money: 200
},{
id1: 01,
id2: 02,
id3: 03,
money: 300
}]
```

the difficult thing I am facing is how to put them into 1 array of employees, with a corresponding amount, for example, task has 3 ids (id1, id2,id3) then money will divide by 3, a task with 2 ids will divide by 2

what I want

```js
var employee = [{
id: 001,
money: 400
},{
id: 002,
money: 400
},{
id: 003,
money: 100
}]
```

I tried the below code but it can only apply with 1 unique id as first id

```js
 var nv = nhanvien.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            var existingnhanvien = nhanvien.find(o => o.id1 === cur.id )
            if (existingnhanvien) {
                existingnhanvien.money= parseInt(existingnhanvien.money+ cur.money)
            }
            else {
                acc.push({
                    id: cur.id1,
                    money: cur.money
                })
            }



            return acc
        }, [])
```

Comment: shouldn't id 01 have 400 money instead of 300?

Comment: yes, 400, i'm wrong

Comment: there can be infinite number of id's right? not just id1,id2,id3?

Comment: Wait shouldn't 1 have 300 since 200+100, but 3 have 200 because 100+100?

Comment: yes infinite number of id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate your `Task` array, and for each object extract keys.

```js
var Task = [{
  id1: 01,
  id2: 02,
  money: 400
}, {
  id1: 03,
  id2: 02,
  money: 200
}, {
  id1: 01,
  id2: 02,
  id3: 03,
  money: 300
}, {
  id1: 01,
  id2: 02,
  id3: 03,
  id4: 04,
  id5: 05,
  id6: 06,
  money: 300
}]

let obj = {}

for (let t of Task) {
  let money = t.money
  
  let keys = Object.keys(t)
  
  // ALL KEYS EXCEPT OF "money"
  keys.splice(Object.keys(t).indexOf('money'))

  // SPLIT MONEY BETWEEN IDs
  let chunk = money / keys.length

  for (k of keys) {
    if (typeof obj[t[k]] == 'undefined') {
      // IF EMPLOYEE DOESN'T EXIST IN OBJECT, INITIALIZE IT
      obj[t[k]] = chunk
    } else {
      // IF EMPLOYEE EXISTS IN OBJECT, INCREMENT ITS VALUE
      obj[t[k]] += chunk
    }
  }
}


let employees = Object.keys(obj).map(key => { return { id: key, money: obj[key] } })

console.log(employees)
```

Comment: what about when task has id number up to 4 id or 5 id?

Comment: just tried, I added another record to `Task` with many ids. It calculates it correctly

Comment: have you tried the id1:003 case? 
it's just column number in excel, sometimes employee number 003, located in column id1 is what can happen, if so your formula might be wrong

Comment: and one more thing, i need an array object, not an object. sr@@

Comment: ok edited the snippet, try it now. please note, being a number, `id1: 01` and  `id1: 001` will always be just `id1: 1`

Comment: ok! thank you very much. 
It took me more than 2 days to think about this, thank you very much

Comment: wait, if so, can't it scale horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Task = [{
id1: 01,
id2: 02,
money: 400
},{
id1: 03,
id2: 02,
money: 200
},{
id1: 01,
id2: 02,
id3: 03,
money: 300
}];

let employee = [];

    for(t of Task) {
        let ids = [];
        if(t.hasOwnProperty("id1")) {
            ids.push(t.id1);
        }
        if(t.hasOwnProperty("id2")) {
            ids.push(t.id2);
        }
        if(t.hasOwnProperty("id3")) {
            ids.push(t.id3);
        }
        let money = t.money/ids.length;

        for(let i of ids) {
            let exists = false;
            for(let e of employee) {
                if(i == e.id) {
                    exists = true;
                    e.money += money;
                }
            }
            if(!exists) {
                employee.push({id: i, money: money})
            }
        }
        
    }

console.log(employee);
```

Comment: what about when task has id number up to 4 id or 5 id?

Comment: task 1: has id1, and task 3 also has id1, task 1 has 2=> money 200, and task 3 has 3 ids, money = 300,=> id1= 100, add up = 400